# Using fullPage.js plugin: I've lost control over header, when I added the video background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

http://testcykuty.cba.pl/

As you can see, the width of thin gray header on my page is higher than the width of the fullscreen slide. And this is the problem here: How can I keep the width of the header to be equal to the width of the slide?

I've made some trial and error:

http://jsfiddle.net/2dhkR/63/ - here you can see how the header should look like. But whenever I add the video background, the width of the header goes nuts (according to: 
`width of header = width of a slide * number of slides`).

```
<video autoplay loop muted id="video">
<source src="Comp 1_1.webmsd.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

... and there goes my header :( Other divs seem to be working alright

Comment: More trial and error: I've simple added <div> on top of <video>, and the header seems to be alright :) But still I'm interested in understanding how does it work!

Comment: The question is not quite clear... I don't understand which is your problem. The with of the grey line at the top is 100%...